# Query to find values based on a like and a not like

Tags: subquery, like

I have a column in a table: ID - this column can have a value of '123456' but can also have value '123456x'.

I need to return all the numbers where there is an 'x' and the same number but without an 'x' doesn't exist.
So if '123456' and '123456x' both exist I don't get a result. If '345678' exists and '345678x' does not exist then I get a result.

I'm sure this must be simple using a subquery and likes but it's wrecking my brain trying to construct the query. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: What is your RDBMS?
What about if `45678` is exist two times? Those need to come in the final result?

Comment: Putting two unrelated things in the same column usually results in headaches. Maybe you need two columns. For example what if someone inserts '123z' instead of '123x'?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify which type of database you are using. Here's a solution that works in Oracle and SQL Server (2022)

```sql
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING 'x' FROM ID) as ID   
FROM table1
GROUP BY TRIM(TRAILING 'x' FROM ID)
HAVING COUNT(TRIM(TRAILING 'x' FROM ID)) <> 2
```

Or if you don't like the duplicate `TRIM()` statements:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM 
(
    SELECT TRIM(TRAILING 'x' FROM ID) AS id
    FROM table1
)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) <> 2
```

Comment: Note the `TRAILING` keyword for the `TRIM()` function and the ability to specify a character (as opposed to just whitespace) is only available in SQL Server 2022.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you may achieve this using sub query and aggregate functions:

```
SELECT S.CleanNumber
FROM (
    SELECT Q.CleanNumber,
           COUNT(Q.IsNumber) AS NumCount
    FROM (
        SELECT REPLACE(NumValue, 'x', '') AS CleanNumber,
               ISNUMERIC(NumValue) AS IsNumber
        FROM TestNumbers
        ) Q
    GROUP BY Q.CleanNumber
    ) S
WHERE S.NumCount = 1
```

Working SQL Fiddle with schema and sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/62o-fRWc

Answer (score 0):

Since it's unclear if you want to keep rows where the same exact value appears twice (e.g. two different rows with the same exact `ID` of `345678`), and the other answers don't keep those rows, I figured I'd give you an answer that does. (If I had to guess, `ID` is unique and it's a moot point, but ‍♂️.)

You can accomplish this with a simple outer join to itself like so:

```
SELECT T1.ID
FROM YourTable AS T1
LEFT JOIN YourTable AS T2
    ON CONCAT(T1.ID, 'X') = T2.ID
    OR CONCAT(T2.ID, 'X') = T1.ID
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL;
```

No need for subqueries, etc. This basically just says: return only the rows where there's no match on an `ID` that ends with an `'X'` to the same `ID` that doesn't end with one.